# PM2 start stuck in infinite loop

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

I am trying to run a number of node services using pm2. Annoyingly, I need to switch to an older version of node to run the services. I use the set PATH command in the command prompt to point to the older version of node. This seems to work as node -v shows the older version.

When I try to run my yaml which contains the configuration details of the services I need to run I used the command pm2 start myApps.yaml. This opens the pm2 table and shows the services as stopped, however the command prompt is continually opening new windows, as if it is constantly restarting the services. This doesn't happen if I use the default version of node, only when I switch to the older version in the command prompt. However, using the default version doesn't let me run the services anyway.

If anyone has experienced the same issue, any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using my work laptop and they do not give developers admin access, otherwise this whole ordeal would be solved as I need admin access to run nvm as administrator.